# Bones moving some vertex groups wrong

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

I have a rigged character as you can see below
[image: T-Pose]

It seems ok in T-Pose, but when I try to move his feet, I get into something odd:
[image]

All of the vertexes are in the same object, the shoes and the ropes ARE moving, but not enough. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably one or more other vertex groups applying influence to the shoes and laces, go through all the vertex groups in weight paint mode and see if anything other than the feet bones are painting the feet.

Comment: Yes, the shoes were connected to Hips too. I don't know why that's possible and what's the usage. But thanks, my problem solved.